# How Do I Launch The SDK Emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

How do I use the Android emulator? I made an AVD device in Eclipse, now im trying to launch it via command prompt. Android is the AVD name. I have also installed all the files for Android 4.2.2 in SDK manager. This is what I type into cmd: `emulator -avd <android> -gpu on`. It spits out, system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: By the way, this question is only marginally on topic for this site. This site is intended for questions about using Android devices. Questions about developing for Android belong on Stack Overflow. The emulator is a bit of a gray area, since it's usually used by developers, but non-developers could have some use for it too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the directory that `emulator` resides in isn't in your PATH. The path isn't updated by the installation of the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have `<`angle brackets`>` around the filename. They're used in examples to show you that you need to change that part of the command (to the AVD name you chose), and you shouldn't type them in.

Comment: Also a good possibility for causing the stated problem. I'm so used to that convention I didn't even consider this answer.

Comment: To be fair, I didn't think of your answer either until I read it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install AVD Manager inorder to run emulator...check for those and try running using the menu Tools|Android|AVD Manager after installing the necessary files and starting them...Wish u have success